# Maven Compilation Error using mvn clean install commad

Tags: java, maven

Hi I have the following project structure and when I'm running `mvn clean install` I am getting compilation error:

Following is my maven project structure:

```
src/main/java(Folder)
 com.test.io(Package)
   BuildDoc.java

src/IT/java(Folder)
 com.io.mytest(Package)
  OpenAmazonPage.java


public class OpenAmazonPage{
public static WebDriver driver;
 void OpenPage(){
 driver=new ChromeDriver;
}


import com.io.mytest.OpenAmazonPage;
class BuildDoc{
 void test(){
    GenericData.take(OpenAmazonPage.driver);
}
```

Then using `mvn clean install` command I m getting following error:

```
package com.io.mytest.OpenAmazonPage does not exist.
```

This might be happening because classes are in two different folders but even after importing it doesn't work.

pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/it/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Comment: What strange package structure is that? "com.io.mytest" and "com.test.io"? First off all, you might want to post your pom.xml file. Do you have a special setup for "IT" folder? Maven works with convention over configuration and expects a certain folder layout, if not configured otherwise: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I have added pom now and yes I'm using build helper plugin to include my src/it/java directory

Comment: Don't do this. Use `src/main/test/<package>/` and use naming conventions to separate between unit tests and integration tests. Apart from that it would be helpful if you could post the error which occurs cause I don't see any error in your post ...

Answer (score 0):

Do I read that correctly, you have:

```
src/main/java/com/test/io/BuildDoc.java
```

trying to include:

src/IT/java/com/io/mytest/OpenAmazonPage.java

Unless you have a very, very strange pom.xml, this can't work.

See the expected folder layout for maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

`mvn install` will go through the [Maven Life cycle Phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and build and run the tests, then build and install the main app.

You are trying to import an integration test file into your main Java artifact. That can't work and should never be done. You use your main Java artifacts **in your tests**, not vice versa. The tests are **not** part of your final build, they are only part of your development environment.

In my experience, you also need additional setup to get different test, integration-test and main folders. Oftern there is only src/main/java and src/test/java.

Comment: Problem is i m trying to use a class which is in src/it/java folder to src/main/java folder even after importing the class

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are importing it or not! The "IT" sources are not part of your main build! You _can't_ import them and you _shoudn't_! Why are you including test classes in your main app?  I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but don't mix tests and app like that. Your tests include your app to test it. Your app mustn't know anything about your test classes. If you need this test class in your app, then move it into the main app.

Answer (score 0):

by default the all the packages + classes `src/main/java` will be added to your class path. 
In order to add `src/IT/java` you might need to add it as source folder for your project  using your project settings.

IF thats not a feasible solution move `com.io.mytest.OpenAmazonPage.java` class with all folders under `src/main/java`